# how to update new version with different Apple ID?

Tags: ios

I want to solve problem and try to understand what is proper way.

Lets say Bob released application with name `MyAppl` and ver. 1.0.1 to App-Store with Bundle ID `Bundle_Bob` and Apple ID `Apple_ID_Bob`.

Now Mike (other guy) whats to release new version (new build) 1.0.2 with the same Name `MyAppl`, Bundle ID `Bundle_Bob` but different Apple ID `Apple_ID_Mike`.

Mike has Bob's account (a.e user/password to iTunes Connect and Distribution provision files).

So what i need to do?

From [apple site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html) *Updates keep the same Apple ID and bundle ID*

how to change Apple ID to new version to `Apple_ID_Bob`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bob should export his distribution key and provide it to Mike.  Mike should log into Bob's developer account and download the relevant distribution certificate and provisioning profile, then import all three into his system.

A quick way of doing that is by using Xcodes "Export developer profile" feature, although it may transfer more than you need.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to transfer ownership of the app and its bundle id to a different iTunes Developer Account. This isn't possible (at least not officially, it's possible you could appeal to Apple, but I kind of doubt it). You will always need to use the same bundle id and the same developer account to update the application. So if you gave up or took over ownership of an app, it will have to always exist under the same Apple ID.